# ElasticSearch: apply filter aggregation on computed results

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I have an elastic search query that calculates total puppies bought per person and only keeps people who bought more than 5 puppies.

My problem is that I want to store the buckets with people having more than 5 puppies in one variable and keep them  separately instead of using a `bucket filter` which removes buckets from the total.

So to summarize my output should be : `allBuckets, moreThan5PuppiesBuckets`. Thank you guys in advance.

```
"aggs": {
    "results": {
        "terms": {
            "field": "person_id"
        },
        "aggs" :{
            "totalPuppiesBought": { "sum":{"field":"num_of_puppies"} }
            "puppiesBucketFilter":          
               "bucket_selector": {
                    "buckets_path": {
                        "totalPuppiesBought": "totalPuppiesBought"
                    },
                    "script": "params.totalPuppiesBought > 5"
                }
              }
       }
```